# images are cropped after updating IOS to 16.4

Tags: iphone, image-cropper, ios16.4

I have a Shopify website. Everything was perfect before updating to IOS 16.4 but once updated, some of the full-width images show cropped.

Any idea what could be causing this trouble in the latest version of IOS?

Screenshot to compare:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csPF3.jpg)

Comment: Please, include the image as part of the post. Don't use external links.

Comment: By iOS 16.4, do you mean the 16.4.1 version?
I would still update to the 16.5 version to see if the error is still there. There were a lot of problems with images in the 16.4 version.